# Error in creating graph from point cloud

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am a new user of C++ and point cloud library version 1.6. I would like to generate a graph based on point cloud data. My This is my cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <pcl/common/io.h>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <pcl/graph/point_cloud_graph.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
  pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud <pcl::PointXYZ>);
  if ( pcl::io::loadPCDFile <pcl::PointXYZ>("xyz_new.pcd", *cloud) == -1 )
  {
    std::cout << "Cloud reading failed." << std::endl;
    return (-1);
  }
//create a graph based on the cloud
pcl::graph::point_cloud_graph<pcl::PointXYZ> graph(cloud);
}
```

However, when I compile it has errors:
Error 1:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/graph/point_cloud_graph.h(117): error C2039: 'vertex_bundled' : is not a member of 'boost::vec_adj_list_impl<Graph,Config,Base>'
       with
      [
          Graph=pcl::graph::point_cloud_graph<pcl::PointXYZ>,
          Config=boost::detail::adj_list_gen<pcl::graph::point_cloud_graph<pcl::PointXYZ>,boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,boost::no_property,boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>,boost::listS>::config,
          Base=boost::undirected_graph_helper<boost::detail::adj_list_gen<pcl::graph::point_cloud_graph<pcl::PointXYZ>,boost::vecS,boost::vecS,boost::undirectedS,boost::no_property,boost::no_property,boost::shared_ptr<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>>,boost::listS>::config>
      ]
```

Error2:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/graph/point_cloud_graph.h(117): error C2146: syntax error : missing ',' before identifier 'vertex_bundled'
C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/graph/point_cloud_graph.h(117): error C2065: 'vertex_bundled' : undeclared identifier
    C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/graph/point_cloud_graph.h(117): error C2955: 'boost::is_same' : use of class template requires template argument list
 C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\3rdParty\Boost\include\boost/type_traits/is_same.hpp(37) : see declaration of 'boost::is_same'
C:\Program Files (x86)\PCL 1.6.0\include\pcl-1.6\pcl/graph/point_cloud_graph.h(117): error C2338: (boost::is_same<typename Base::vertex_bundled, boost::no_property>::value)
```

File point_cloud_graph.h is from the link: http://taketwo.github.io/tcs/point__cloud__graph_8h_source.html

Comment: What version of boost are you using?

Comment: I am using boost version 1.50.0

Comment: You need at least 1.53. Also I should admit that I never tested it on Windows.